# Zenject GameObject Injection

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, zenject

I'm using [Zenject](https://github.com/modesttree/Zenject) framework and I'm using multiple `GameObject` for a class but I don't know to do it using Zenject Container. Here's my code:

```
private GameObject _canvas;
private GameObject _mainWindow;
private GameObject _createAccountWindow;

void Awake()
{
    _mainWindow = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainWindow");
    _canvas = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Canvas");
    _createAccountWindow = GameObjectExtensions.FindObject(_canvas, "CreateAccountWindow");
}
```

Is it possible to inject these objects from Zenject Container? If it is, how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Zenject, those classes would be injected like this:

```
[Inject]
GameObject _canvas;

[Inject]
GameObject _mainWindow;

[Inject]
GameObject _createAccountWindow;
```

However, when you're using DI, it usually injects based on the type, so having them all be type 'GameObject' will make this difficult.

But if you make it something like this:

```
[Inject]
Canvas _canvas;

[Inject(Id = "MainWindow")]
RectTransform _mainWindow;

[Inject(Id = "CreateAccountWindow")]
RectTransform _createAccountWindow;
```

Then also add ZenjectBinding components to each of these, and add a value for the Identifier property of ZenjectBinding, then it should work.  (I'm assuming they are already in the scene at startup here)

Comment: Is there a way to inject a game object with id via constructor or method injection, not property injection?